# Cannot achieve a cover index with this table (2 equalities and one selection)?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

```
CREATE TABLE `discount_base` (
  `id` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `family` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_CUSTOMER` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT` (`family`,`customer_id`,`amount`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) 
      REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I've added a cover index `IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT` on `family`, `customer_id` and `amount` because most of the time I use the following query:

```
SELECT amount FROM discount_base WHERE family = :family AND customer_id = :customer_id
```

However using `EXPLAIN` and a bounce of records (~ 250000) it says:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'discount_base', 'ref', 'IDX_CUSTOMER,IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT', 'IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT', '40', 'const,const', '1', 'Using where; Using index'
```

Why I'm getting **using where; using index** instead of just **using index**?

**EDIT**: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23fc5/3) with a small amount of data (**Using where; Using index**):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT amount
FROM discount_base
WHERE family = '0603' and customer_id = '20000275';
```

Another [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23fc5/4) where `id` is `family` + `customer_id` (**const**):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT amount
FROM discount_base
WHERE `id` = '060320000275';
```

Comment: You might have collation conflicts with the strings you are passing in as parameters.  That could effect index usage.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: You'll be surprised, `CREATE TABLE tab (col CHAR(1), INDEX(col)); EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE col = 'A'` also gives `Using where; Using index`...

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem.  It would seem "obvious" that the `IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT` index would be used for this query:

```
SELECT amount
FROM discount_base
WHERE family = :family AND customer_id = :customer_id;
```

"Obvious" to us people, but clearly not to the optimizer.  What is happening?

This aspect of index usage is poorly documented.  I (intelligently) speculate that when doing comparisons on strings using case-insensitive collations (and perhaps others), then the `=` operation is really more like an `in`.  Something sort of like this, conceptually:

```
WHERE family in (lower(:family, upper(:family), . . .) and . . .
```

This is conceptual.  But it means that an index scan is required for the `=` rather than an index lookup.  Minor change typographically.  Very important semantically.  It prevents the use of the *second* key.  Yup, that is an unfortunately consequence of inequalities, even when they look like `=`.

So, the optimizer compares the two possible indexes, and it decides that `customer_id` is more selective than `family`, and chooses the former.

Alas, *both* of your keys are case-insensitive strings.  My suggestion would be to replace at least one of them with an auto-incrementing integer id.  In fact, my suggestion is that basically *all* tables have an auto-incrementing integer id, which is then used for all foreign key references.

Another solution would be to use a trigger to create a single column `CustomerFamily` with the values concatenated together.  Then this index:

```
KEY IDX_CUSTOMERFAMILY_AMOUNT (CustomerFamily, amount)
```

should do what you want.  It is also possible that a case-sensitive encoding would also solve the problem.

Comment: See my updates. Do you think I should use the `id` concatenating `family` and `customer_id`?

Comment: Gordon, what makes you think the index is not used?

Comment: By "being used" I mean full used for the `where` and `select` clauses.   The `explain` says that it is not being used fully for the query.

Comment: This is not my understanding of the documentation. It clearly says there that the index is used completely, and that anything necessary is present in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Are family and customer_id strings? I guess you could be passing customer_id maybe as a integer which could be causing a type conversion to take place and so the index not being used for that particular column.

Ensure you pass customer_id as string or consider changing your table to store cusomer_id as INT.

If you are using alphanumeric Ids then this don't apply.

Comment: Whatever you have for the _literal_ (`:family`, etc) will be converted once and cached.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure `Using index` is the important part, and it means "using a covering index".

Two things to further check:

```
EXPLAIN FORMT=JSON SELECT ...
```

may give further clues.

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

will show you how many rows were read/written/etc in various ways.  If some number says about 250000 (in your case), it indicates a table scan.  If all the numbers a small (approximately the number of rows returned by the query), then you can be assured that it did do what that query efficiently.

The numbers there do not distinguish between read to an index versus data.  But they ignore caching.  Timings (for two identical runs) can differ significantly due to caching; Handler% values won't change.

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information) on `EXPLAIN` has this to say:

> Using index
>
> The column information is retrieved from the table using
>   only information in the index tree without having to do an additional
>   seek to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query
>   uses only columns that are part of a single index.
>
> If the Extra column
>   also says Using where, it means the index is being used to perform
>   lookups of key values. Without Using where, the optimizer may be
>   reading the index to avoid reading data rows but not using it for
>   lookups. For example, if the index is a covering index for the query,
>   the optimizer may scan it without using it for lookups.

My best guess, based on the information you have provided, is that the optimizer first uses your `IDX_CUSTOMER` index and then performs a key lookup to retrieve non-key data (amount and family) from the actual data page based on the key (customer_id).
This is most likely caused by cardinality (eg. uniqueness) of the columns in your indexes. You should check the cardinality of 
the columns used in your where clause and put the one with the highest cardinality first on your index. Guessing from the column 
names and your current results, `customer_id` has the highest cardinality.

So change this:

```
KEY `IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT` (`family`,`customer_id`,`amount`)
```

to this:

```
KEY `IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT` (`customer_id`,`family`,`amount`)
```

After making the change, you should run `ANALYZE TABLE` to update table statistics. This will update table statistics, which can 
affect the choices the optimizer makes regarding your indexes.

Comment: Nothing changed. Did analyze + optimize after dropping the index and switched the columns.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds fine. According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information):

> If the *Extra* column also says *Using where*, it means the index is being
>   used to perform lookups of key values. Without *Using where*, the
>   optimizer may be reading the index to avoid reading data rows but not
>   using it for lookups. For example, if the index is a covering index
>   for the query, the optimizer may scan it without using it for lookups.

That means, *Using index* alone would read entire index to retrieve the results, but not using the index structure to find specific values. You probably could get this with `SELECT family, customer_id, amount FROM discount_base`. *Using where; using index* means the optimizer exploits the index to find and retrieve rows matching query parameters (family, customer_id).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question relies on what the engine is actually using your index for.

In given query, you ask the engine to:

1. Lookup for values (WHERE/JOIN)
2. Retrieve information (SELECT) based on this lookup result

For the first part, as soon as you filter the results (lookup), there's an entry in `Extra` indicating `USING WHERE`, so this is the reason you see it in your explain plan.

For the second part, the engine does not need to go anywhere out of one given index because it is a covering index. The explain plan notifies it by showing `USING INDEX`. This `USING INDEX` hint, combined with `USING WHERE`, means your index is also used in the lookup portion of the query, as explained in mysql documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

> Using index
>
> The column information is retrieved from the table using only
>   information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek
>   to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses
>   only columns that are part of a single index.
>
> If the Extra column also says Using where, it means the index is being
>   used to perform lookups of key values. Without Using where, the
>   optimizer may be reading the index to avoid reading data rows but not
>   using it for lookups. For example, if the index is a covering index
>   for the query, the optimizer may scan it without using it for lookups.

Check this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cdf2/10

I removed the where clause and the query now displays `USING INDEX` only. This is because no lookup is necessary in your table.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed could be a problem.

Note, that there might be millions of string matching by a single index key using the `utf8_unicode_ci` collation. For example, all these letters are matched by the same index key:

*A, a, À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å, à, á, â, ã, ä, å, Ā, ā, Ă, ă, Ą, ą, Ǎ, ǎ, Ǟ, ǟ, Ǡ, ǡ, Ǻ, ǻ, Ȁ, ȁ, Ȃ, ȃ, Ȧ, ȧ, Ḁ, ḁ, Ạ, ạ, Ả, ả, Ấ, ấ, Ầ, ầ, Ẩ, ẩ, Ẫ, ẫ, Ậ, ậ, Ắ, ắ, Ằ, ằ, Ẳ, ẳ, Ẵ, ẵ, Ặ, ặ.*

And there are substantial grounds for believing that then processing an query using `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` index, MySQL in addition to regular index lookup performs full linear scan of all the values matched by index to make sure it is indeed matched by the original query parameter. This may be really needed when the index collation and the `WHERE` collation do not match, but I don't know why it do so all the time, even when this is clearly not needed (in your case for example).

See this question for an evidence and additional details: [Why performance of MySQL queries are so bad when using a CHAR/VARCHAR index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439959/why-performance-of-mysql-queries-are-so-bad-when-using-a-char-varchar-index)

Answer (score 1):

I would only recommend this solution:

1. Remove `amount` from index like:

> ```
> KEY `IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT` (`family`,`customer_id`)
> ```

2. When you do request force `USE INDEX`:

> ```
>  USE INDEX (`IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT`)
> ```

That trick allow to avoid `Using where`. Hope performance will also be on acceptable level:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86f46/2

```
SELECT amount FROM discount_base 
USE INDEX (`IDX_FAMILY_CUSTOMER_AMOUNT`)
WHERE family = '1' AND customer_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fiddle provided, it appears that only numeric values are being used for family and customer id. If this assumption is correct, changing these columns to numeric and using just a single key on customer and family appears to have resolved the issue.

Please check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7c3d/1/0)